# How to stop shutdown script from running at startup (see body)

Tags: raspbian, boot, berryboot

I installed the x735 shutdown script on my pi with the x735 board. The script allows the hat to provide power, and then safely shutdown on button press. I upgraded the board to a x728 which allows batteries, and when i start it up, the x735 script automatically runs and shuts the pi down. Normally one could just go into the SD card and remove the file, but I am unable to do that due to the filesystem type (berryboot). What all this means is that I need a way to halt the startup scripts without editing SD card, either through key combination or something else. Here is [Link to bad script.](https://github.com/geekworm-com/x730-script)

Thanks and I know this might not be possible!

Comment: What happens if you boot without the hat on?  Does that give you a chance to edit the script?

Comment: @Andyroo That is the most obvious solution but that should be a last resort as i would have to spend half a day taking apart and putting back together the whole project

Comment: In Berryboot, install another OS. Boot into that new one, then fix your other OS's root partition from there.

Comment: I'm curious... what do you feel would motivate one to spend essentially the same as the cost of a new RPi on an item of hardware with [documentation like this?](https://geekworm.com/products/raspberry-pi-x735-safe-shutdown-auto-cooling-expansion-board)

Comment: @Seamus i agree that the x735 is a stupid product, i don't recommend, what i do recommend is the x728 which i got to replace it. Finally, a UPS that can supply enough Amps for the Pi 4.

Comment: @Botspot Thats a good idea, i didn't know one could access files from another OS. Do you know which file i should delete? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with your procedure at all, but you can try mounting the other OS's root partition, then finding and deleting all files containing "x730" in the filename.